# can not select input form in css div

Tags: html, css

Just got a jquery responsive menu tab but when I wanted to use that with forms I am not able to select the forms to insert a value.. I think this might be a css problem which I am unable to find..

Please help me.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="container">

    <header>
        <h1>Editing </h1>
        <p><a href="../home/">Back to home</a></p>
    </header>
```

===========

## from here i cannot select any content

```
        <span id="one" class="anchor"></span>
        <div class="panel">
            <a class="tab-link" href="#one">Status</a>
            <div><p>



            <form method="post" action="">
        <table width="250">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="id" value="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

            </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span id="two" class="anchor"></span>
        <div class="panel">
            <a class="tab-link" href="#two">Balance</a>
            <div>
                <p>Sed mauris eros, accumsan consectetur tempor quis, pulvinar non mi. Etiam placerat ipsum a felis convallis quis aliquet lacus gravida. Cras eget sapien arcu, a pellentesque elit. Duis porttitor urna et velit convallis fringilla. Sed eu porttitor lorem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam egestas pulvinar eros vel convallis. Phasellus viverra posuere nibh vitae luctus.</p>

                <p>Proin eget nibh ante, ac vulputate felis. Donec aliquet, est sagittis ultricies faucibus, enim tortor malesuada dui, vel tincidunt mauris ipsum at metus. Donec non nunc augue. Ut purus tortor, mattis sit amet suscipit at, volutpat ac justo. Morbi facilisis enim nec leo iaculis aliquam. Vestibulum tempor magna sed ligula consequat sit amet congue est eleifend. Fusce faucibus hendrerit convallis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span id="three" class="anchor"></span>
        <div class="panel">
            <a class="tab-link" href="#three">Info</a>
            <div>
                <p>Vestibulum porta venenatis odio, eu iaculis urna iaculis ut. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In tempor, arcu vitae tristique gravida, nibh tortor suscipit sapien, euismod lacinia diam orci id turpis. Fusce ut rutrum lacus. Pellentesque vitae nisi et ipsum posuere eleifend at at magna.</p>

                <p>Vestibulum libero nibh, rhoncus quis euismod sit amet, mattis sed mauris. Aliquam in quam nisl, non cursus diam. Nam hendrerit, quam eget rhoncus rhoncus, eros est tincidunt tortor, quis posuere purus est vel nunc. Pellentesque hendrerit semper nisl a feugiat. Mauris suscipit eros vel neque ultricies hendrerit.
            </div>
        </div>

        <span id="four" class="anchor"></span>
        <div class="panel">
            <a class="tab-link" href="#four">Pic</a>
            <div>
                <p>Sed aliquam, erat eget ornare semper, ipsum nisl tristique velit, ac commodo turpis lacus vel ipsum. In accumsan scelerisque lacus quis consectetur. In lobortis volutpat metus, eget rutrum metus viverra.</p>

                <p>Phasellus dui ligula, imperdiet quis porta id, sagittis ac sapien. Nam mi risus, posuere et tempus ac, lobortis et justo. Cras molestie iaculis nisl et tempus. Sed interdum, ante eget rhoncus semper, tortor velit suscipit enim, vitae sollicitudin libero metus a sem. Quisque consequat porta purus, et suscipit enim porttitor hendrerit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </article>


</div>
```

here is the css i have

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    font: 90% arial;
}

article, header {
    display: block;
}

header h1, header p {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

header a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    position: relative;
}

    span.anchor {
        position: fixed;
        display: none;
    }

    .panel div {
        opacity:0;
        background: #eee;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 19px;
        left: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
    }

        .panel .tab-link {
            margin-top: -20px;
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #eee;
            margin-right: .5%;
            text-decoration: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            color: #333;
            text-align: center;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
            -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
            transition: all 0.6s ease;
        }

            .panel .tab-link:visited {
                color: #333;
            }

    .anchor:target + .panel div {
        opacity: 1;
        background: #ccc;
    }

        .anchor:target + .panel .tab-link {
            background: #ccc;
        }

@media screen and (max-width:300px) {

    .panel .tab-link {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    }

}
```

please help me to fix..

Comment: Provide a fiddle please.

Comment: okay here is the site from where I got it, they have a demo..
http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/responsive-css3-tabs/

Comment: This is a demo, it will surely work but It will be better to post a fiddle to show what problem are you facing.

Comment: okay.. here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yyuy7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an assumption, because you haven't actually added a fiddle for us to check thoroughly,

But i assume that you have other elements absolutely positioned over your form, which are stealing the clicks.

This is evident as you have a `position:absolute` property on your `.panel div` selector, along with a `top:0`.
seeing as this rule will catch several panels and their divs, it is safe to assume that you have some stacking over eachother.

you need to rethink your CSS so that you don't stack over your elements.

you can test if this is true by opening the page in chrome, right clicking an element, selecting inspect element, and seeing what element was selected.

if a different element than what you had in mind was selected, you need to move it from over your form.

**Off the top of my head**:
adding `position:relative` to `.panel` might help. or perhaps removing the absolute positioning on your divs.

Comment: JSFiddle is a web app that allows you to show us snippets of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ create a test case in here, compile, and post the link.

Comment: Well, this seems to work.
try adding other elements of your original code until it stops working as you reported.

Comment: okay I've seen that but it works if I add only one tab but if I add more tabs next to it this dont work..

here is the full coded link
http://jsfiddle.net/Yyuy7/1/

Comment: This shows exactly what i said in my answer, the other tabs are still in the document, they are just completely transparent. there is a difference between not-displayed and transparent. transparent elements still act out normally on the document. you should change `opacity:0` and `opacity:1` to `display:none` and `display:block`

Comment: What you should do in this case is mark my answer as correct.